# Delete Webhooks Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, webhooks

In discord.py, I know you can create webhooks with:
`message.channel.create_webhook(name = 'something')`

But I don't know if there is an option to delete them. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AxelSparrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8460260/axelsparrow)'s method is definitely cleaner, but there is a built-in method of deleting them via [`webhook.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=webhook#discord.Webhook.delete), though this might be a bit 'scuffed' since you'd have to use a for loop if you only have your webhook's name. In the code snippet below, I will provide two methods you can use.

```py
# Method 1: Directly using the information from creating the webhook
hook = message.channel.create_webhook(name = 'something') # create a variable
# await hook.send("test")
await hook.delete() # then delete based on variable

# Method 2: Only use this if you don't have the webhook's other information
# get all the webhooks in a channel ⬇️
channel_webhooks = await message.channel.webhooks() 
for webhook in channel_webhooks: # iterate through the webhooks
    if webhook.name == "something":
        await webhook.delete()
        break
```

Do feel free to view the [`class discord.Webhook`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=webhook#discord.Webhook) documentation if you require further information or understanding.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method to do this, [you will need to send an http request manually](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#delete-webhook).

(EDIT -  It appears I was wrong: as shown in Bagle's answer, there is indeed a built in method to delete webhooks. However, this method still works and is a little easier on the eyes.)

Something like:

```py
await ctx.bot.http.request(Route('DELETE', '/webhooks/{webhook_id}', webhook_id=webhook_id))
```

You may need to adjust this to work in your implementation.